# Support for additional management port for accessing /actuator endpoint in Undertow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, undertow

Based on an answer to a past Spring Boot [question](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22362). I need to add an additional actuator port in Undertow instead of Tomcat.

**My code:**

```
@ManagementContextConfiguration(ManagementContextType.CHILD)
public class SecondActuatorPortConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ServletWebServerFactory undertowCustomizer() {
        
        UndertowServletWebServerFactory factory = new UndertowServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.addBuilderCustomizers(new UndertowBuilderCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Builder builder) {
                // I need to expose 9090 (management.server.port=9090) 
                // and additional port, lets say - 9091
                builder.addHttpListener(9091, "0.0.0.0");   
            }

        });
        return factory;
    }

}
```

**In Application.properties:**

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration=SecondActuatorPortConfiguration
```

But With these, I am only able to access on -> http://127.0.0.1:9090/actuator
but not on http://127.0.0.1:9091/actuator

Comment: you can't do it on the same process. the actuator is adding endpoint on the existing container's listener and its not a separate listener. btw spring application.properties are starting with ```spring.```

Answer (score 2):

`application.properties` isn't the right place to tell Spring Boot that `SecondActuatorPortConfiguration` should be treated as configuration for the management context. As described in the javadoc for `@ManagementContextConfiguration`, the configuration should be registered using `META-INF/spring.factories`. The `spring.factories` file needs to be included in your jar so its full path relative to the root of your project should be `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As you mentioned, I have added in :- `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`. Additional Port has been opened if I do - `netstat -tulpn | grep :9091`. But If I try to access the endpoint, then it shows Whitelabel Error Page (status=Not found). Can you suggest some lead on this

Comment: Adding the HTTP listener should be all that's necessary. It works for me. Perhaps you can update your question or ask a new question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have asked new question on :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952159/whitelabel-error-coming-when-trying-to-integrate-managementcontextconfiguration

Comment: I am getting error in logs: `web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler","message":"Resource not found"`. Even If remove META-INF/spring.factories, then also I am getting same error