# Whitelabel Error coming when trying to integrate @ManagementContextConfiguration in META-INF/spring.factories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, undertow

I am building Spring boot gradle application. I am trying to add an additional port for the actuator endpoint with Undertow.

**Code**: SecondActuatorPortConfiguration.java

```
package com.test.config;

import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextType;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@ManagementContextConfiguration(ManagementContextType.CHILD)
public class SecondActuatorPortConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public UndertowBuilderCustomizer aa() {
        return (undertow) -> {
            // I need to expose 9090 (management.server.port=9090) 
            // and additional port, lets say - 9091
            undertow.addHttpListener(9091, "0.0.0.0");
        };
    }
}
```

**src/main/respurces/META-INF/spring.factories** :

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration=\
com.test.config.SecondActuatorPortConfiguration
```

**Hierarchy of files:**
[Hierarchy of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq3W7.png)

---

Till now, all the changes have been made as per [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22362).
But, if do `netstat -tulpn | grep :9091` , then port is Listening but if I access this via `http://127.0.0.1:9091/actuator`, then Error:
***Whitelabel Error Page (type=Not Found, status=404)*** is coming

Comment: In what package is the rest of your application's code?

Comment: In `src/main/java/com/test/rest` has rest APIs and `src/main/java/com/test/service'`has service classes. Even if I remove spring.factories from my project, then same error is coming. Means spring.factories is not able to do configuration, so only port is being opened but cannot map to actuator path. Hence, it is showing 404 not found (Whitelabel Error)

Comment: I suspect that `SecondActuatorPortConfiguration` is getting picked up by component scanning because it's in the same package or a sub-package of your main class. A [minimal reproducible example](/help/mcve) would confirm if this is the case.

Comment: Application.java is in `src/main/java/com/test/`. If I put `SecondActuatorPortConfiguration` in same package as of Application.java or in sub-package, means in `src/main/java/com/test/config` or in `src/main/java/com/test` respectively, then Whitelabel error (404 not found, resource mapping not found) is coming. But If I put `SecondActuatorPortConfiguration` in separate package `src/main/java/com/portConf` , means in same hierarchy package as of Application.java, then even port is not opening and hence it can't connect